# C++ / Cuda template

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem using CUDA and VS 2015 using the following code:

main.cu

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo<uchar4> f(make_uchar4(1, 2, 3, 4));
    f.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    f.stop();
    return 0;
}
```

foo.h

```
#include <thread>

template<typename T>
class foo
{
public:

    foo(T value);

    void start();

    void run();

    void stop();

private:
    T _value;
    std::thread _thread;
    bool _run;
};

#endif //__FOO_H__
```

foo.cu

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

template<typename T>
foo<T>::foo(T value)
{
    _run = false;
    _value = value;
}

template<typename T>
void foo<T>::start()
{
    _run = true;
    _thread = std::thread(&foo<T>::run, this);
}

template<typename T>
void foo<T>::run()
{
    while (_run)
    {
        std::cout << "YOLO ! " << _value.x << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void foo<T>::stop()
{
    _run = false;
    if (_thread.joinable()) _thread.join();
}

template class foo<uchar1>;
template class foo<uchar2>;
template class foo<uchar4>;
```

This sample is pretty simple. It creates an object `foo` and then call the methode `start` to start a thread that will display "YOLO". The main thread sleep for 2 seconds then stop the YOLO thread. That's all !
When i try to build this with Cuda 8.0 and Visual Studio 2015 I have this error : `C2292: 'foo<uchar1>': best case inheritance representation: 'virtual_inheritance' declared but 'single_inheritance' required` It appears for all different types that I declare with `template class foo<uchar1>;`

I have no explanation about this error. I tried to build this on a Debian using g++ 5.4 and CUDA 8.0 and it works perfectly ! In the same way, I removed all reference to CUDA and, using c++ and VS 2015 only, again it works.

Does someone have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: I think this is a VC++ optimization gone amok. This is the most useful discussion I could find:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.vc.language/JEaeWsbAQvo/YRNE3LsWlo4J

Comment: I'm not sure on how I should understand it. Does it mean that `template class foo<uchar1>;` is considered as forward declaration? or maybe the template itself?

Comment: Seems to me like this isn't actually about CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two workarounds for your problem: put everything for the foo class in the header file or declare your class

`class __single_inheritance  foo`

This is a wild stab in the dark, but I think the compiler is trying to use an optimization technique (as I pointed to in the comments) that is stymied by the incomplete type and how VC++ handles instantiation/translation units.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. As you said, normally everything should be in the header file, I did not do that to keep as clean as possible the header files in our project. The solution (and I do not know why it works like this) is to write the definition `template class foo<uchar1>;` in the header file instead of the .cu file. About the optimization, the stranger thing is that this sample works in a simple c++ project but not in a Cuda project.